# É usual lidar com sessões em um aplicativo Android?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, session

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: eu tenho um servidor Rails e faço consultas nesse servidor usando um aplicativo Android. Se eu estivesse criando um sistema web, eu faria o uso de sessão par administrar as permissões do meu sistema. No entanto, como eu tenho o aplicativo, eu faço as restrições dentro do mesmo (se o usuário não efetuar login, não terá acesso ao sistema).

O medo que eu tenho é que alguém utilize as rotas que criei no Rails para acessar dados restritos dos usuários e fazer a inserção de dados de forma fraudulenta. Tem alguma maneira de contornar isso?

Answer (score 1):

O mais comum é usar servidores *stateless* para comunicação com aplicativos. Isso quer dizer que você vai controlar os acessos e as permissões através de tokens. Dê uma olhada em OAuth. Se você colocar essas permissões no aplicativo dá quase no mesmo que nada, é muito fácil o cara burlar.

Comment: Mas pelo que eu entendi o OAuth só serve quando eu quero usar alguma conta da Google ou Facebook para fazer login. E no caso de eu permitir o cadastro dentro do meu app?

Comment: O Google e o Facebook usam OAuth, você pode criar o seu servidor OAuth e receber os tokens dele